# Golang execute child process from binary data in memory

Tags: go, memory, exec, executable

I know that it is possible to [embed executables in Golang executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796043/how-to-embed-files-into-golang-binaries) and run them, or run Golang code from a string using projects like [Yaegi](https://github.com/containous/yaegi), but is it possible to run a binary stored as a variable **without writing it to a file**, as a child process? The binary is already in memory as a variable so is it possible to just execute it somehow?

If I'm not mistaken there is a difference between executable memory and data memory so would that prevent this from being done?

The reason for my question is that I'm writing a RAT/payload dropper as a project to learn Go(lang) and would like to make is as modular as possible, including file-less updates and binary (also file-less) payloads.

EDIT: Any solution is welcome, but cross-platform solutions are preferred.

EDIT2: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523769/8623347) SO answer, this is not possible / very difficult in C++. Seemingly, the main reason for this is dynamically linking libraries. As Golang is statically linked, would this be any easier?

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of the downvote is. I believe this is a legitimate question which I have researched beforehand. I have linked similar questions too which do not quite answer my question and added a further question to highlight the difference. Can I have some constructive criticism?

Comment: Take a look at https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/11/05/how-to-jit-an-introduction -- you could do all that with Go using syscalls or cgo. Running Go code like that is trickier, though, since it would need load-time relocation/linking, etc.

Comment: @EliBendersky I certainly will. Just from a quick glance it looks pretty interesting and useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this way to do this.
https://github.com/amenzhinsky/go-memexec

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, it seems like that project actually creates a temporary file and executes it as opposed to using what's already in memory :(

Comment: As of version 0.5.0, the author of go-memexec has updated behavior (for Linux) to mount allocated memory as a process instead of creating a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no portable way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You seem to imply that there are non-portable ways to do it though. Is that the case?

Comment: @TR_SLimey Yes.

Comment: Could you give some examples, like some links or keywords to search for? While single-platform code is not ideal I am doing this mainly to learn the language so it would still be helpful.

Comment: @TR_SLimey You are not going to learn anything about the language while using syscalls and cgo.

Comment: I take it that means I should look at how to do that in C and then use Cgo? Thanks.